# How to delete multiple bigquery datasets of a project in single bq command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have around 200 `BigQuery` datasets in my project. I want to delete them as I am doing some cleanup activities. I see the command `bq rm -r -f -d <var>project_id:dataset</var>` which is for single dataset and i need to run each time. Is there anyway to delete bulk datasets in a project ?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `bq` doesn't have anything like that which implies that if you want to use only the `bq` command you have to delete the datasets one by one.

As a workaround, you can use `SHELL` script to automate the deletions.

In the code bellow, for example, you can use `bq list` to get all the datasets inside your project and loop through the results deleting all of them:

```
for ds in `bq ls -d`; 
    do bq rm -r -f -d <your-project>:$ds;
done
```

If you don't want to delete all the datasets inside a project but you have a list of the datasets you want to delete, you can define an array with the dataset's names and then loop through it as bellow:

```
declare -a arr=("dataset1" "dataset2");
for ds in ${arr[@]}; 
    do bq rm -r -f -d <your-project>:$ds;
done
```

Please let me know if it helps you or if you want some extra information.

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine this statement with `grep` in order to filter only the datasets you'd like to remove, for example:

```
for ds in `bq ls -d | grep -i my_pattern`; 
    do bq rm -r -f -d <your-project>:$ds;
done
```